# Xml Serialization: Can't define same namespace in parent and child element

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

i need to create a xml structure similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ns0:RootElement xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns0="http://fuu.gub">
  <ns0:ChildElement xmlns:ns0="http://fuu.gub">
    <ns0:Data>Some-data</ns0:Data>
  </ns0:ChildElement>
</ns0:RootElement>
```

The namespace ns0 must be defined in the RootElement and in the ChildElement.
I'm using Xml.Serialization to serialize my objects and i cant get this done.
The serializer is ignoring the namespace on the child element because it's already defined in the parent. This means i end up with the following result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ns0:RootElement xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns0="http://fuu.gub">
  <ns0:ChildElement>
    <ns0:Data>Some-data</ns0:Data>
  </ns0:ChildElement>
</ns0:RootElement>
```

Here is my code

```
[XmlRoot("RootElement", Namespace = "http://fuu.gub")]
public class RootElement
{
    [XmlNamespaceDeclarations]
    public XmlSerializerNamespaces XmlNamespaces { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ChildElement")]
    public ChildElement Child { get; set; }

    public RootElement() {
        XmlNamespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        XmlNamespaces.Add("ns0", "http://fuu.gub");

        Child = new ChildElement();
    }

    public void ToXml(string path)
    {
        XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(this.GetType());

        TextWriter txtW = new StreamWriter(path);
        x.Serialize(txtW, this);
    }
}


[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://fuu.gub")]
public class ChildElement
{
    [XmlNamespaceDeclarations]
    public XmlSerializerNamespaces XmlNamespaces { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public string Data{ get; set; }

    public ChildElement()
    {
        XmlNamespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        XmlNamespaces.Add("ns0", "http://fuu.gub");

        Data = "Some-data";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp I found this:

> When a namespace is defined for an element, all child elements with
> the same prefix are associated with the same namespace.
>
> Namespaces can be declared in the elements where they are used or in
> the XML root element
>
> **Note:** The namespace URI is not used by the parser to look up
> information.

When you define a namespace, you can´t use the same prefix to define another/the same namespace again.

I believe you can use the same namespace with a different prefix though.